# Load data from excel to matlab

Tags: excel, matlab

I'm trying to download data from excel to matlab. I downloaded data from yahoo finance. I want to load them in matlab however it's not successful. Right down here you have my codes and the message matlab is sending to me. Can somebody help me to improve my codes?

> load SP100Duan.csv
>
> Error using load
>   Number of columns on line 18 of ASCII file   C:\Users\11202931\Desktop\SP100Duan.csv
>   must be the same as previous lines.

Comment: You're trying to read a CSV file. The `load` function is for MAT-files (see the documentation). Try `csvread` or `textscan` or `importdata`. Also, a CSV file is a general file format and is not specifically related to Excel.

Answer (score 1):

There are a TON of ways to get data into MATLAB. Generally speaking, mixed text/numbers gives MATLAB problems. You may want to clean up the excel file so there is no text in columns that should be numbers. Some possible methods to load data:

1. Use readtable function. Eg. `mytable = readtable('mycsvfile.csv')` All your data is put a table datatype, which I personally find convenient.
2. You can read data directly from an excel file using `xlsread` function. From your description, it sounds like your datatype is a .csv file though.
3. Use csvread function.
4. You can often copy and paste data in excel directly into a variable in Matlab. eg. (i) type: `x = 0`, then (ii) double click on x variable in your workspace, then (iii) copy data from excel and paste into your x variable (iv) execute something like `save mydata.mat` so you can later load it with `load mydata.mat`

Comment: I have tried this code:  [Prix dates] = xlsread('SP100Duan.xlsx', 'Feuil1', 'A2:B1003'); but it gives me this:                                                                              Error using xlsread (line 129) XLSREAD unable to open file 'SP100Duan.xlsx'. File 'C:\Users\11202931\SP100Duan.xlsx' not found. How is it possible? I have downloaded all the file on my desktop.

Comment: Type `pwd` command to show your current working directory. Unless further specified, xlsread will try to read from your current working directory, not the desktop.

Comment: pwd                                                                                                                          ans =

C:\Users\11202931\Desktop                                                                     I type pwd on my command window in matlab then i just got this code code above. I put all my files on my desktop. I should run anyway!

Comment: And if you type `ls` command, the file is there, but if you call xlsread, it says the file is not there?

You're almost certainly doing something screwy such as a typo somewhere.

Comment: >> ls

.            ..           Projet       desktop.ini                                                                            It says me that my file is not there. I typed ls and pwd and they all said that my code are on my desktop!

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty simple . . .

xlsread('C:\Apple.xls', 'Sheet1', 'A1:G10')

Also, please see this link.
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html