# Retrieve column name based on cell value using matlab and excel

Tags: excel, matlab, excel-formula, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

[image]

[image]

I use matlab software for programming language. I stored my data first is color as column & second value as number from Matlab to excel file.

How can I retrieve color name (column / text /string) where color value as number is greater than 1.6155 for example if my `threshold = 1.6155` then i retrieve column name such as ("Merah ma","Kuning","Hijau")

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Load data from excel to matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33598625/load-data-from-excel-to-matlab)

Answer (score 0):

Apply transpose to your data so that column name such as ("Merah ma","Kuning","Hijau") and their respective values are converted into 2 columns.

Apply a simple condition in 3rd column that if(A2>1.6155,"Match","") and it will display match against those names which have a higher value than your threshold limit.

For Excel, this will work